# How to check the arguments of the auto generated Phoenix paths

Tags: phoenix-framework

> No helper clause for Api.Router.Helpers.v1_user_organization_path
>   defined for action :show with arity 3. Please check that the function,
>   arity and action are correct. The following v1_user_organization_path
>   actions are defined under your router:
>   * :create
>   * :index
>   * :show
>   * :update

#### router.ex

```
defmodule Api.Router do
  use Api.Web, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Api do
    pipe_through :api

  end

  scope "/v1", Api.V1, as: :v1 do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/users", UserController, only: [:create, :show, :update] do
      resources "/organizations", OrganizationController, only: [:create, :update, :index, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

and when I do mix phoenix.routes I see the following `v1_user_organization_path` getting generated. The problem is I don't know how to use it and I don't know what I should pass into it. Is there a way I can check what this generated method accepts?

The error I get is occuring here

#### organization_controller.ex

```
def create(conn, %{"user_id" => user_id, "organization" => organization_params}) do
    changeset = Organization.changeset(%Organization{}, organization_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, organization} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", v1_user_organization_path(conn, :show, organization))
        |> render("show.json", organization: organization)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(Api.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

At `put_resp_header("location", v1_user_organization_path(conn, :show, organization))`

Comment: Since it's a nested resource, you probably want `v1_user_organization_path(conn, :show, user_id, organization.id)`?

Comment: @Dogbert yes, you're right but how do I know? For example, in Java you just look at the function declaration or Haskell you can do do :type to see what it expects.... I feel like I'm playing guess and check in Elixir.

Comment: To add to that, I mainly use strongly, statically typed languages and it's confusing to me how you figure out what the expected argements are (especially functions that were generated for you) without either an IDE or looking at the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the auto generated documentation for the router helper functions using `h` in `iex -S mix` and reading the output of `mix phoenix.routes` for some help. For example, for the following routes:

```
resources "/posts", PostController do
  resources "/comments", CommentController
end
```

I get:

```
iex(1)> h MyApp.Router.Helpers.post_comment_path
def post_comment_path(conn_or_endpoint, action, post_id)
def post_comment_path(conn_or_endpoint, action, post_id, params)
def post_comment_path(conn_or_endpoint, action, post_id, id, params)
```

```
$ mix phoenix.routes
post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments           MyApp.CommentController :index
post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit  MyApp.CommentController :edit
post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/new       MyApp.CommentController :new
post_comment_path  GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id       MyApp.CommentController :show
post_comment_path  POST    /posts/:post_id/comments           MyApp.CommentController :create
post_comment_path  PATCH   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id       MyApp.CommentController :update
                   PUT     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id       MyApp.CommentController :update
post_comment_path  DELETE  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id       MyApp.CommentController :delete
```

It's not clear from just the function signature which action accepts how many arguments, but if you read the output of `mix phoenix.routes`, you can see that `:show` (last column) requires a `post_id` and an `id`.

The output of `h` is also not completely accurate because it doesn't tell you that the arity 4 version also accepts `(conn_or_endpoint, action, post_id, id)` and not just `(conn_or_endpoint, action, post_id, params)`.

I don't think there's any better auto generated documentation for the generated route functions right now in Phoenix. I usually just look at the output of `mix phoenix.routes` and pass in `conn_or_endpoint` followed by the `action` followed by every `:var` in the route, optionally followed by a params map.